# The "Palette" doesn't show Richfaces or Ajax4Jsf library after Richfaces installation

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am try to add richfaces to my jsf project.
My IDE is Eclipse Helios, Tomcat 6. I had my project setup as Dynamic web project, configured with JSF 1.2 (Mojarra JSF API Implementation), 
added jsf-facelets.jar, jstl-api-1.2.jar, jstl-impl-1.2.jar to web-inf/lib.

I have a page masterPage1.jsp, it runs fine before adding richfaces library to web-inf/lib.
After I added richfaces-api-3.3.3.final.jar, richfaces-impl-3.3.3.final.jar, richfaces-ui-3.3.3.final.jar, commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-digester-2.1.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar.

The "Palette" doesn't show Richfaces or Ajax4Jsf libary. 
Also I following code in web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
  <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <filter>
  <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Install [JBoss Tools Eclipse plugin](http://labs.jboss.com/tools/).